# working of Softlockup in the kernel

Tags: kernel, watchdog

Softlockups are defined to occur if the watchdog task (real-time) doesn't update the time stamp at the hrtimer callback.

Now, if a bad thread is stuck in the kernel (looping), why won't the scheduler be able to schedule the watchdog task? I mean, the faulting thread will continue to loop, but the scheduler would periodically move it out of context. So I don't understand why the WD task will not be able to update the time stamp?

Comment: what is your definition of "bad thread"?   the kernel scheduler will not be able to interrupt the thread (based on hardware timer), if the thread has disable timer interrupt, so potentially the thread will used the CPU forever, without ever giving other threads or tasks a chance to execute.

Comment: @PeterTeoh: What you are describing is a case of a hardlockup, for example, if I do a spinlock_irq_save and never release it, kernel will eventually lockup and dump trace. However, I'm asking a specific case of a soft lockup where threads are still running but the watchdog task cannot run because of reasons other than interrupts being disabled. 
By "bad thread" i meant any thread that is causing a lockup/panic in the kernel.

Comment: linux kernel's WD task are meant for usermode process to use.   so if a process (in user mode) is not able to feed the dog in time, the WD tasks will reboot the kernel, as it assume the usermode process has hung.   Correct?   I do that all the time - putting a gdb attach to a process that is monitoring the /dev/watchdog device driver, and after some time, the whole OS will reboot.   that is part of the design.   of course NOT reboot the whole OS is possible, but watchdog is meant to guarantee responsiveness within certain time limit.     I really cannot understand your question.   sorry.